# Initializing Application scoped bean in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, web-applications, spring-mvc

I want to initialize a bean or an ArrayList like a list of key value pairs for all the drop downs in the application that can be used across sessions application wide. And Want to happen during the application start-up. I tried implementing the ServletContextListener and added the beans to the context, but it didn't work.

Any suggestions as to how I can achieve this. Thanks.

Ravi

Answer (score 0):

Define a regular (singleton) Spring bean and initialize your values either in constructor, or @PostConstruct method:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
@Component
public class AppBean {

@PostConstruct
protected void init() {
    // executed after dependencies have been injected. initialize values here
}

}
```

See http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-postconstruct-and-predestroy-example/ for more detailed example